# When does random forest feature importance fail?

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

I'm curious about the assumptions of random forest feature importance.

In this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010933404324), the author says that

> "We show that random forest variable importance measures are a sensible means for variable selection in many applications, but are not reliable in situations where potential predictor variables vary in their scale of measurement or their number of categories."

I don't understand what it means by "predictor variables vary in their scale of measurement." Is this referring to the need to standardize data before fitting a random forest model?

1. Does RF based feature importance require standardization of features?
2. Does it require fitting a good RF model (ex: pruning), as if I'm making an actual prediction with RF?
3. What do I do if I have categorical variables and continuous variables at the same time? Is permutation method the only option?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this, but tree based models don't require scaling as such as that's just another value to split for them instead of the unnormalized one

Comment: The reasons for this and a solution (implemented at least in R package `ranger`) are well explained in this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6198850/

Comment: Too many levels can make random forests act (slightly) pathologically.  There are fixes, and healthy systems account for it.  I like Boruta.